# Clearing cache of feed dialog in facebook app

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, caching, cookies

I have a facebook app that uses the feed dialog:

```
FB.ui({ 
method: 'feed', 
message: '', 
link: 'http://mywebaddress/pathToContent', 
picture: 'http://mywebaddress/pathToPhoto/photo.jpg', 
display: 'popup'
});
```

When I used the app to share content, I forgot to upload the image so the share dialog appeared with the image broken. Now I uploaded the image but it no way I can get it to show up.

1) Tried to use the debugger and it shows in the og:image correct but of course the feed dialog is different from the og tags so it is of no use in this case.

2) It works well from other accounts. Only mine is broken because I tried to share without uploading the image.

3) Tried in different browsers and tried to clear cookies,cache,etc...

4) It works if I rename the file

Do you know a way to force clear the facebook cache or it should go by time or what?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've been dealing with a similar issue with Facebook cache. You can try using

```
curl -v https://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/?url=YOUR_URL_HERE&format=json
```

In console window. That didn't work in my case but I was trying it on a web page not an app so you might have better luck. Hope it helps.